# Populating a datagridview with a list C#

Tags: c#, list, datagridview

I'm trying to populate a datagridview on a form with a list of objects with multiple properties in order to create a table.

```
  private void display()
  {
        DataGridViewName.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        DataGridViewName.DataSource = Class.List;
        DataGridViewName.ClearSelection();
  }
```

When I have AutoGenerateColumns set to false, nothing shows up in the cells (I used designmode to input column headers), if I change AutoGenerateColumns to true, it adds a column for each parameter and the column header shows the name of the property. Any explanation why the data isn't showing with it set to false, and if not then is there a way to change the column header name from the property name to something else on the autogenerated columns?

Comment: If you created the columns in the designer, does each columns `DataPropertyName` match one of the class properties names?

Comment: That was it! The datapropertyname in design mode was blank, once I changed it to the property name it fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: @LP, also I will advise you to not set this property in designer, because you a creating _"magic string"_. Suppose some days after you will rename your properties and your `DataGridView` go Boom. It is better to set it by code in constructor: `yourColumn1.DataPropertyName = nameof(YourClass.YourProperty);`

Comment: @vasily.sib good call, that makes sense. adjusting accordingly

Comment: @vasily.sib … I have to ask from your comment… _”I will advise you to not set this property in designer, because you a creating "magic string".”_ … I am not sure how this property qualifies as a “magic string.” Can you elaborate why this is a “magic string.”?  In addition, your next comment… _”Suppose some days after you will rename your properties and your DataGridView go Boom.”_ …. ??? I can only recommend you more carefully “rename your properties.”

Comment: @JohnG, sure. Visual Studio have some kind of "Find & Replace" functionality. When you rename some of your class properties, press `Ctrl + .` and select option `Rename <old_name> to <new_name>`. Then, VS will find each and every place, where this property is in use and rename it too, so you `DataPropertyName` will stay up to date. And this make sense, as you set it to the **actual name of a property**, not to **some string literal that coincides randomly with the property name of a certain class**.

Comment: @vasily.sib  .. I am obviously missing something. I understand the “find and replace”, however, I do not understand why setting the columns `DataPropertyName` in the “Designer” as opposed to setting it in the main code would make any difference in a properly implemented find and replace? Obviously, assuming the “find and replace” is set for the entire solution and not just the current file. Again, I must be missing something.

Comment: @JohnG When you set it in designer, resulting code in `YourForm.Designer.cs` file will be `this.yourColumn1.DataPropertyName = "YourProperty";` in this situation `DataPropertyName` is setted to **some string literal that coincides randomly with the property name** ("magic string") and will not be automatically renamed with `YourProperty` property of `YourClass` class. In other case your code will be `yourColumn1.DataPropertyName = nameof(YourClass.YourProperty);` and now it is setted to **actual name of a property** (no "magic string") and "Find & Replace" will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `AutoGenerateColumn = false`

and set `DataPropertyName` for each column

and then you could change the header setting `HeaderText` property